# protractor - try catch - error handling

Tags: protractor

I am looking for an element and if the element is not present, I want to give a decent error message saying "element not present"; but it comes out of the block and throwing a message like element not found for the `xpath`.

Below is the code I have tried but I'm still getting the same error. 
For example a=protractor and  if the value is present, it says text prevails - protractor; and in case it is not there, instead of saying element not present/error occurs it says "no element found `element(by.xpath("//div[@title='"protractor"']"))` followed by a big error message. 
How to resolve this?

```html
this.gridverify = function (a) {
        browser.sleep(10000);
        try {             
            var elm = element(by.xpath("//div[@title='" + a + "']"));
            if (elm.isPresent) {
                elm.getText().then(function (x) {
                    console.log("text Prevails: " + x);
                })
            }
            else {                   
                console.log('element not present');
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log('error occured');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at your xpath `//div[@title='"protractor"']` . It should be `//div[@title='protractor']` . Are you getting me?

Comment: @KishanPatel, thanks for looking into it. when i copy pasted, it happened; that is not a issue. i have passed the right one.

Comment: You manually go to that page and try to inspect with the same `xpath` and see whether element found or not. `//div[@title='"protractor"']`

Comment: Another Thing : Try to put `if ` in try block and `else` in  catch block

Comment: @KishanPatel i have tried manually and it is detecting the element; i will try the if and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
browser.wait(until.presenceOf(element(by.className("user-thumb"))),5000,'Element not present');

browser.wait(until.presenceOf(element(Add Locator here)),wait time,'Add Message you want to print in case element not found');
```

This might resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider digging more deeply into promises. Your code has a lot of errors. http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.html

```
this.gridverify = function (a) {
    browser.sleep(10000); // Why this needed? Can you update to .wait() ?
    var elm = element(by.xpath("//div[@title='" + a + "']"));
    elm.isPresent().then(present => {
        if (present) {
            elm.getText().then(function (x) {
                console.log("text Prevails: " + x);
            })
        } else {
            console.log('element not present');
        }
    }, err => {
        console.log('error occured', err);
    })
}
```

Your try/catch won't work as you expecting in async code.

Comment: thankyou for checkcing...will look into the link and give a try